# How to simultaneously process signal from MIC input and save it to a file?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I want to do some signal processing on the MIC input, and in parallel write the original audio into a file.

Currently I'm using `AudioRecord` with `ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` to process the signal in real time, but the output file comes out too large to save. So the signal has to be encoded before saving.

Can I do that on Android in real time?